# Bootstrap number input spinner won't stop spinning

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, spinner

**[Demo on Bootsnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-number-spinner-on-click-hold)**

**Issue:**

*If you hold left click on + or -, then right click, move your mouse away from the + or - button and let go of both clicks, the "mouseup" function will never fire, and it will keep adding or substracting numbers and you can't stop it.*

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanations in the code below:

```
$(function() {
    var action;
    $(".number-spinner button").mousedown(function () {
        btn = $(this);
        input = btn.closest('.number-spinner').find('input');
        btn.closest('.number-spinner').find('button').prop("disabled", false);
        // You're creating a new interval on every mousedown (left and right click)
        // You need to clear the previous interval to make this work.
        clearInterval(action);
        if (btn.attr('data-dir') == 'up') {
            action = setInterval(function(){
                if ( input.attr('max') === undefined || parseInt(input.val()) < parseInt(input.attr('max')) ) {
                    input.val(parseInt(input.val())+1);
                }else{
                    btn.prop("disabled", true);
                    clearInterval(action);
                }
            }, 50);
        } else {
            action = setInterval(function(){
                if ( input.attr('min') === undefined || parseInt(input.val()) > parseInt(input.attr('min')) ) {
                    input.val(parseInt(input.val())-1);
                }else{
                    btn.prop("disabled", true);
                    clearInterval(action);
                }
            }, 50);
        }
    }).mouseup(function(){
        clearInterval(action);
    }).mouseout(() => {
        // Added to stop spinning when mouse leaves the button
        clearInterval(action);
    });
});
```

**Recap**:

1. Clear the previous interval on `mousedown`.
2. Clear the interval on `mouseout` also.

Answer (score 0):

The `mouseup` event will only fire for an element if the mouse is over that element when the mouse button is released.

You could add your handler to the `document` and then delegate to child controls from there.

Or could just add another handler for `mouseout` and clear your interval on that event.